# Passing array from NodeJS server to client?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Learning to make a webiste on my own.  I had this issue before with a single object, but I was able to make it work and pick up the object on the client side and use it.   But, now I'm trying to send an array of locations to the client in order to render them on the google maps api as markers (they have placeIDs stored in the JSON).  According to the threads I've read once cannot send an array like an object, but I followed what some others suggested to no avail.  I have some test locations I've made an array of, but when I try and pick it up on the client side I just get, "SyntaxError: missing : after property id" and "ReferenceError: cityList is not defined", which makes sense if the cityList is having issues.

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var yourCities =  ["stockholm", "moscow", "barcelona", "bordeaux", "helsinki", "london"];
    var cityList = yourCities.reduce(function(cityList, city) {
        cityList.push(require('../public/cityData/' + city))
        return cityList;
    }, [])

    //TODO::need to update this to send an array
    res.render('map', {
        cityList : JSON.stringify(cityList),
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Trying to get the cityList clientside and make it into markers, the marker code is basically copied straight from Google's API guide.

```
  <script>
      var cityList = <%- cityList %>;
  </script>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 41.9028, lng: 12.4964},
        zoom: 3
      });

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      for(i = 0; i < cityList.length; ++i)
      {
        service.getDetails({
          placeId: cityList[i].placeID
        }, function(place, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: place.geometry.location
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                place.formatted_address + '</div>');
              infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Obviously, I'll later make marker placement into a loop but for now I'm just trying to get the first element for testing.

EDIT:: THE CODE IN HERE NOW IS WORKING FOR FUTURE USERS

Comment: JSON is an sting with the signature of `{"key":"value"}`. You should send your data in this style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems your way to sending data to `ejs` template is right and it should work fine, to be sure log the first item of `cityList` as bellow:

```js
var cityList = <%= cityList %>
console.log(cityList[0])
```

**Update:**

`server`

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var yourCities =  ["stockholm", "moscow", "barcelona", "bordeaux", "helsinki", "london"];
    var cityList = yourCities.reduce(function(cityList, city) {
      cityList.push(require('../public/cityData/' + city))
      return cityList;
    }, [])

    //TODO::need to update this to send an array
    res.render('map', {
        cityList : JSON.stringify(cityList),
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: OK, so you're saying send it as an array within a JSON object?  How would I build it in the javascript that way and then how would I extract it on the other side?

Comment: How do you get `cityList` inside `map` template?

Comment: So to update I used this answer to build my data server side and it worked.  Then to pick it up client side I used:

  var cityList = <%- cityList %>;

which for reasons I don't understand successfully puts the cityList in the var and nothing else does.  If someone could explain why I need the ejs javascript indicators I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify the array (or any arbitrary JSON object really) on the server and then JSON.parse it on the client.

So you need to change the client side code little bit.Please try below code it's working for me.

server-side:

```
res.render('map', {
    cityList : JSON.stringify(cityList),
});
```

client-side:

```
var cityList = JSON.parse( !{JSON.stringify(cityList)} );
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was doing and having issues with?

Comment: There is a little bit difference in client-side code, You are parsing with out stringify but i am first converting it to string then parsing.