# Passing array of objects from backend to front end

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to pass array of objects from backend to front end.

app.js

```
       router.post('/submits',urlencodedParser,function(req,res)
         {
          //getLocation function returns an array of objects
           getLocation(req.body.latval,req.body.longval)       
           res.redirect('./table');
          });
      router.get('/table',function(req,res)
        { 
          res.render("table");
         });
```

table.js (front end)

```
window.onload= table();
function table(array)
{
    var table = document.getElementById("table");

    for(var i = 0;i<table.rows.length;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<table.rows[i].cells.length;j++)
      {
        table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = array[i][j];
      }
    }

  });
```

So I am trying to send the array as a parameter to the function in table.js. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing array from NodeJS server to client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494482/passing-array-from-nodejs-server-to-client)

Comment: First you need to load it with `http get`, use `$.ajax`.

Comment: I would post the answer, but you should learn it yourself :)